# How to send “<br>” element to client from server or how to return innerHTML in helper in meteor ?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How to send `“<br>”` element to client from server in meteor?

I want to send text with escape new line character to client from server.

I tried with `"<br>"` element directly to client but it is taking as text rather than element.

Any help appreciable.

Comment: To override HTML-escape in Handlebars, use the triple-stash with your text

`<span>{{{yourvariable}}}</span>`

Comment: Thankyou, @AmitSuhag,
Ya it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override HTML escape in Handlebars, use the triple slash with your text

`<span> {{{yourvariable}}} </span>`